# MySQL rollback on the MyISAM engine

Tags: mysql, myisam

By mistake I ran the update query. This update made my table all rows values as o.

Is it possible to rollback the table values?

Comment: mistake is am not taken the backup...

Comment: Not sure if you can rollback without transactions -

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

MyISAM does not support transactions. Therefore, every individual statement runs as if it is enclosed by a transaction. You cannot roll it back.

Answer (score 3):

MYISAM dont support transaction support..

That's the reason best you should be using INNODB..

Answer (score 1):

If you have no backup, and didn't run your update in a transaction, your data is gone for good.